# "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" happening on files

Tags: python, hash

I'm using the following script to find the hash values of all the files in a directory, but I keep having an issue with some random files giving me the above error. I'm using the absolute path to folders and have successfully used this script on about 100 gb of files in about 20 different folders, so I know the script does work. The files that the errors come from don't seem to have an issue with their names that would cause problems (for example one was named like title65name77.dwg). The files aren't empty and can be opened in their respective programs.

```
import csv
import hashlib
import os

folder_path = input('What folder do you want to get hashes from? ')
output_file = input('What do you want the output CSV file to be named? (include .csv at the end of the file name)')

# Generate hashes of files
def hash_file(file_path):
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b''):
            hasher.update(chunk)
    return hasher.hexdigest()

# Record hashes & filepaths
def record_hashes(folder_path, output_file):
    hashes = {}
    for root, _, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            file_hash = hash_file(file_path)
            hashes[file_path] = file_hash

    # Write hashes and file paths to a CSV file
    with open(output_file, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['File Path', 'Hash'])
        for file_path, file_hash in hashes.items():
            writer.writerow([file_path, file_hash])

record_hashes(folder_path, output_file)

print("Done recording hashes of files in", folder_path)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You said you are using the absolute path to the files, where do you do that in the code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.